# AutoLayout - how to bind two view and change size accordingly

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, constraints

i want something who seems simple at first glance, but i can't figure out how to make it nicely from IB.

I want something simple, let's say i have two view into one parent (a view container that hold the two children). What i want is that they are each connected to vertical space at 0 px (one to his top the other to the bottom of the other). So that when one of them change his size the other occupy the remainder size, and so there're will still be connected at 0 pixel each other.

I've put two screenshoots of what i want.

[image]
[image]

I've tried lot and lot, and nothing is working like i'm expecting.

What is strange that even if i put the priority at the vertical space, the other constraints take priority, and i just get a warning from XCode that my verticalSpace constraint is wrong.

Could someone help me ? I didn't find a specific tutorial on this kind of view managements.
Thanks

*** EDIT ***

Ok i figured out:
I finally read the entire tutorial of Ray as suggested, and it helped me a lot (to my defense, i have read before the IOS official documentation about constraints, and it has confuse me more than helped me). To me, what was hard to understand is that now you can't change UIView by frame but now by constraint. When I understood this, it was really easy to make the changes.

By the way i tried the @Handsomeguy's response, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: What action happens when you change a views size in your case? For this to really work, I would make constraint IBOutLets to the viewController - then update them when the view needs to change its size.

Comment: Hi Tander, actually i am lost. Constraint look like so inuintuitive, i can't figure out how to make a simple action as simple as this. When i add constraint, i get lot and lot of error and warning.

Comment: Okay, I had the same issue as you - getting confused my constraints. Take a look here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1 it helped me understand it better. 
That will bring you up to speed on auto layout. As I was trying to say earlier - When you want the views to change - maybe a button changes them? then you can update the values of the constraints and this will re-draw them again on screen in their new positions.

Comment: Ok thanks Tander. I will check a look at this. The fact is I woulnd't want to spend 10 hours to understand the concept. But i think I need this. All i want to know is if i change one contraint, the other will fit nicely, and if i can check this from IB. If you say that it's possible, then i hope i'll will success. What i don't like in the raywender tutotrial, is that's it's much about configuring view into parent view size change, that relative to children views.

Comment: Shouldn't take you more than an hour or two at most to go through that tutorial. Having a solid understanding of AutoLayut will help. You can then make connections from your constraints in IB to your viewController and update them when you need to, to reposition the views on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use autolayout. You need the following constraints:

```
both views pinned to left and right edge of containerView
redView top pinned to containerView top
yellowView top pinned to redView bottom
yellowView bottom pinned to containerView bottom
height constraint on **either* redView **or** yellowView!
```

This is very easy using this category:
https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout

**UPDATE**

I just noticed you said you wanted to do it in IB. You can use the same principle here, but I find it is much more convenient (and also easier to read later) if you use the category mentioned. There will be very few lines of code, and the code will clearly show the intent.

** UPDATE 2**

An explicit height constraint may not be necessary if the intrinsic size on one view is changed. This depends on what kind of views the yellow and green views are.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need at least one height constraint (with IBOutlet to your view controller) on one of your views... when you change its constant value, the other view should automatically change. You can try on storyboard first, and then write down the logic. But without an height constraint on one of them I don't think it will ever work.

Comment: Hi Stefano, how do you do that? The fact is when i add one constraint (like adding a constant size or a vertical space to another object), IB always tell me to add 10000 others constraint. So i can't figure out after how that work.

Comment: In your example I would add:
- a leading and a trailing constraint on both subviews to the parent container
- a top constraint on top view to the superview
- a bottom constraint on bottom view to the superview
- a vertical spacing of 0px between  the two views
- a height constraint on the view you want to resize.
then you create an IBOutlet from the height constraint to the view controller and edit via code to resize the view

Comment: I was changing the view size in order to see change on the constraint. Are you saying I should do the exact opposite? Changing the height constraint value of one view so that the other view will have his size modified nicely?

Comment: Exactly. The constraint.... CONSTRAINTS the size of the view to specified value :) I suggest you to check out the RayWenderlich's tutorial as other suggested, it's easy to understand and really useful. I was in your situation some month ago and that post clarified  so many things! :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it by setting constraints in interface builder:

1. vertical spacing: top layout guide -> yellow
2. vertical spacing: yellow -> red
3. vertical spacing: red -> bottom layout guide
4. height: yellow

Set an outlet to the height constraint, then to change the height of the yellow view just use `_height.constant = NEW_HEIGHT`

You can probably omit the height constraint if the top view reports it's intrinsic content height appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Without auto layout it would be as easy as putting an anchor-bottom on the yellow view, and putting an anchor-top on the red one. Now, when you change the parent view, the views would resize 50/50.

Comment: The fact is that i don't want to change the parent view. I just want that when one of the children view change its size, the other do as well. Because i don't know the children view size at complie time

Comment: How do you change size on views? If you're using autolayout you shouldn't change directly the view frame, but edit appropriate constraints instead